# setting ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> in a ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

Can we set an `ArrayList` containing `HashMap` into an `ArrayAdapter`?

i am using

```
ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> ad= 
new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
```

but this gives me an error saying

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>(searchname, int, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined.
```

Comment: You may want to use a `SimpleAdapter` instead

Answer (score 8):

@nikhil you can you use below code, as this works for me.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inviteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();  
     for(int i=0;i < inviteListRespone.size();i++)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("id",String.valueOf(i));
        map.put("emailID", inviteListRespone.get(i).getEmail());
        inviteList.add(map);
    }
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, inviteList, R.layout.invite_list_view,
            new String[] { "emailID" },new int[]{R.id.inviteTextView});

    listBoth.setAdapter(adapter);
```