# Android using HashMap data on ListView

Tags: android, listview

i customized android `AlertDialog` to have simple `ListView` into that and i'm using HashMap data for that,

getProvince method return 30 record and i save that into

`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> provinceHashMap = new ArrayList<>();`

getProvince:

```
private void getProvince() {
        String                  province = Provinces.getProvinceData();
        HashMap<String, String> salam;

        try {
            JSONObject data    = new JSONObject(province);
            JSONArray  RECORDS = data.getJSONArray("RECORDS");

            for (int p = 0; p < RECORDS.length(); p++) {
                JSONObject object = RECORDS.getJSONObject(p);
                salam = new HashMap<>();
                salam.put("id", object.getString("id"));
                salam.put("name", object.getString("name"));
                provinceHashMap.add(salam);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

now when i use that to show items my listview have empty data:

```
private void showStatePopup() {
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityGetPersonInfo.this, R.style.PopupTheme);
    final View          mView    = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_select_state_and_city, null);
    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    listView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, provinceHashMap, R.layout.invite_list_view,
            new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.inviteTextView});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            int    itemPosition = position;
            String itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ostan)).setText(itemValue);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.8f);
    dialog.show();
}
```

`getProvince();` called from `onCreate()`

UPDATE:

`Provinces.getProvinceData();` return this value:

```
public static String provinceData = "{\"RECORDS\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"آذربایجان شرقی\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"آذربایجان غربی\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"اردبیل\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"اصفهان\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"ایلام\"},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"بوشهر\"},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"تهران\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"چهارمحال بختیاری\"},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"خراسان جنوبی\"},{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"خراسان رضوی\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"خراسان شمالی\"},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"خوزستان\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"زنجان\"},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"سمنان\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"سیستان و بلوچستان\"},{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"فارس\"},{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"قزوین\"},{\"id\":18,\"name\":\"قم\"},{\"id\":19,\"name\":\"کرج\"},{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"كردستان\"},{\"id\":21,\"name\":\"كرمان\"},{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"كرمانشاه\"},{\"id\":23,\"name\":\"كهكیلویه و بویراحمد\"},{\"id\":24,\"name\":\"گلستان\"},{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"گیلان\"},{\"id\":26,\"name\":\"لرستان\"},{\"id\":27,\"name\":\"مازندران\"},{\"id\":28,\"name\":\"مركزی\"},{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"هرمزگان\"},{\"id\":30,\"name\":\"همدان\"},{\"id\":31,\"name\":\"یزد\"}]}";
```

Comment: what do u want to display in the list??

Comment: From where method showStatePopup() called? can you please post full class code?

Comment: @AvinashRoy displaying `name` values from json keys which its saved into hashMap

Comment: @FAT after click on some widget on view i'm calling `showStatePopup()` method

Comment: u cannot push an array list of hashmaps into the adapter just like that

Comment: @AvinashRoy reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456953/setting-arraylisthashmapstring-string-in-a-arrayadapter

Comment: I hope you're callng getProvince first and then showStatePopup.

Comment: @AakashVerma `getProvince` called on `onCreate` before clicking on widget to call `showStatePopup`

Comment: Add some log to showStatePopup  to chek the size of provinceHashMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add after set adapter

```
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```